# Is there a way to remove a shared folder from my view via the Google Drive API in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

At the end of my Python script, my goal is to delete a number of folders from a shared drive after I've downloaded them. However I am not the owner of these folders, and I get a 403 PermissionError when I try to do this, even if I give myself what look like the correct scopes:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
    for folder_id_to_delete in google_drive_folders_to_delete:
    try: 
        service.files().delete(fileId=folder_id_to_delete).execute()
        print(f"Deleted folder: {folder_id_to_delete}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Could not remove folder: {folder_id_to_delete}: {e}")
```

Strangely enough, when I manually navigate there, I can select those folders, and click the trash button to "remove" them, no problem. Then what's weirder is, when I programmatically get the list of folders in that main shared folder? Those no longer show up:

```
def list_folders_in_folder(service, folder_id):
page_token = None
folder_ids = []
while True:
    results = service.files().list(
        q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and (mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType='application/zip' or mimeType='application/x-zip-compressed') and trashed = false",
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, createdTime)",
        pageToken=page_token).execute()
    folders = results.get('files', [])
    for folder in folders:
        print(f"Folder ID: {folder['id']}, Folder Name: {folder['name']}")
    folder_ids.extend([folder['id'] for folder in folders])
    page_token = results.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
return folder_ids
```

Programmatically this allows me to achieve my goals: I effectively can remove the folders so next time I run the program? The "removed" ones won't show up.

Problem is, I need to do that last step manually. And I'd rather not do shitty Selenium automation where I literally have it click the buttons to delete the folders. Is there a way to get the equivalent result via the Google Drive API?

Because apparently I can't officially "delete" them via the Google Drive API, since I'm not the owner. ChatGPT insists that what happens here is I'm simply removing the folders from *my view* -- but OTHERS in the shared folder will still be able to see the folders. But is there a way to get this equivalent end result, some way via the API to make it so they don't show up anymore in my view, either when I actually navigate there or search for the folders list programmatically?

Maybe some function to "trash" them or "hide from my view" or something?

Thanks!

Comment: I got the same 403 PermissionError when I tried this instead:
    try:
        service.files().update(fileId=file_id, body={'trashed': True}).execute()
        print(f"Trashed file: {file_id}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Could not trash file: {file_id}: {e}")